# what path reduces magnetic field strength

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm having trouble solving this particular problem in Colley's Vector Calculus.  I believe my trouble lies in not being able to set up a differential equation.  Here is the problem;

Igor, the inchworm, is crawling along graph paper in a magnetic field.  The intensitiy of the field at the point $(x,y)$ is given by $M(x,y)=3x^2+y^2+5000$.  If Igor is at the point $(8,6)$, describe the curve along which he should travel if he wishes to reduce the field as rapidly as possible.

So, the section this is in is Directional Derivatives and the Gradient, and so this is a gradient problem.  Since we are minimizing magnetic field strength, we are looking for $-\nabla{M(x,y)}$ and we can easily find this at any point.  In this case, $(8,6)$.  But how do we go about doing this starting at a point and following the path for the entire magnetic field?

EDIT:  If it isn't necessary, please don't give me the answer.  Guidance would be much more appreciated, since I want to understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Igor always moves in the direction of fastest decrease of $M(x, y)$, he follows a path $(x(s), y(s))$ such that $\frac{d}{ds}(x(s), y(s)) = -\nabla M(x, y)$, where $s$ is the distance or arc-length along $(x(s), y(s))$.  Now $\nabla M(x,y)= (6x, 2y)$, so Igor's path satisfies the system of ordinary differential equations $x'(s) = -6x$, $y'(s) = -2y$.  How convenient!  The variables are already seperated for Igor and ourselves!  It is easy to see, by solving this simple, decoupled system,  that $x(s) = x_0e^{-6s}$ and $y(s) = y_0e^{-2s}$, where the initial point is $(x_0, y_0)$.  So Igor's path is $(8e^{-6s}, 6e^{-2s})$.  Note that this path, as does any path satisfying $\frac{d}{ds}(x(s), y(s)) = -\nabla M(x, y)$, heads right into the point $(0, 0)$, where $M(x, y)$ clearly attains its global minimum value of $5000$.   And, there I suppose, Igor gets stuck! (Actually, he never *quite* gets there! ;))  Don't know exactly what the graph paper has to do with this, though . . .   ;)

Comment: I know the graph paper helped me visualize Igor walking on a flat surface with level curves of M on it, but I suppose looseleaf would have been just as arbitrary!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Christopher Ernst:  Oh yeah, just joking around, I know how useful gridded paper can be . . . and glad to be of service.  Cheers, Bob Lewis

Answer (score 1):

Your system of differential equations is
$$
\begin{cases}
x'(t) = - 6 x(t)\\
y'(t) = - 2 y(t)
\end{cases}
$$
which can be easily seen is solved by $x(t) = e^{-6t}$, $y=e^{-2t}$.

Comment: while I see the implication, I never got to solving systems in my differential equation class.  Also, the book I am using has not given any lessons in such machinery either.

Comment: As a matter of fact your book does not require you to solve the equations, but only to describe the curve...

Comment: This is true, and it gives an answer of "Travel along the path $y^3=27x$ toward the origin."  I got the negative gradient and it results in that you have above.  But how to get the curve $y^3=27x$ is what I am struggling with.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst the differential equation $x'=-6x$ can be solved by separation of variables. $dx/dt = -6x$ thus $dx/x=-6dt$ integrate to get $\ln |x|=-6t+C$ then exponentiate to obtain $|x|=exp(-6t+C)$ which is the same as $x=kexp(-6t)$ for $k \neq 0$. Finally, observe $x=0$ is also a solution hence $k$ need not be restricted. The same goes for $y$. There are other ways, but this is most elementary modulo guessing.

Comment: okay, so basically once you know the system in x(t) and y(t), you can set them equal to one another with the appropriate variables (since $y=-6e^{-2t}, y^3=-216e^{-6t}$, and then since $x=-8e^{-6t}$ and $8*27=216$) and thus the curve $y^3=27x$.  Thanks.  I had no problem finding gradient of M, but the chapter focuses on single point gradients.  Thanks for walking me through it everyone!